# Android Activity to Service class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have My Activity Below which plays the ShoutCastURL Streaming using Some Helper Classess

Code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.androidworkz.androidshoutcastlib.AndroidShoutcastLib;
import com.androidworkz.androidshoutcastlib.InvalidStreamURLException;
import com.androidworkz.androidshoutcastlib.Metadata;
import com.androidworkz.androidshoutcastlib.MetadataListener;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Player extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener, MusicFocusable {

    private Boolean playState = false;  
    private String station = "http://38.101.195.5:9156";
    public static final float DUCK_VOLUME = 0.1f;
    private String artistName = null;
    private String trackName = null;

    private TextView artist;
    private TextView track;
    private TextView status;
    private Button play;

    enum AudioFocus {
        NoFocusNoDuck, // we don't have audio focus, and can't duck
        NoFocusCanDuck, // we don't have focus, but can play at a low volume
                        // ("ducking")
        Focused // we have full audio focus
    }

    private AudioFocus mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.NoFocusNoDuck;

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
    private AndroidShoutcastLib shoutcast;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    AudioFocusHelper mAudioFocusHelper = null;

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // create the Audio Focus Helper, if the Audio Focus feature is
        // available (SDK 8 or above)
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            mAudioFocusHelper = new AudioFocusHelper(getApplicationContext(),
                    this);
        }
        else {
            mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.Focused; // no focus feature, so we always "have" audio focus
        }

        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist);
        artist.setSelected(true);

        track = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track);
        track.setSelected(true);

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View btn) {
                if (!playState) {
                    play.setText("Pause");
                    handler.postDelayed(handlePlayRequest, 300);
                }
                else {
                    play.setText("Play");
                    status.setText("Press Play");
                    handler.postDelayed(handlePlayRequest, 300);
                }
            }

        });

        shoutcast = new AndroidShoutcastLib();

        try {
            shoutcast.setShoutcastUrl(station);
        } catch (InvalidStreamURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        shoutcast.setOnMetadataChangedListener(new MetadataListener(){

            @Override
            public void OnMetadataChanged(Metadata item) {
                artistName = item.artist;
                trackName = item.track;             
                updateMeta();
            }
        });

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);      
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        shoutcast = null;
        handler.removeCallbacks(handlePlayRequest);
    }

    public void updateMeta() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely modify Views
                artist.setText(artistName);
                track.setText(trackName);
            }
        });
    }

    private final Runnable handlePlayRequest = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (playState) {
                Log.d("Player", "Stop Called");
                giveUpAudioFocus();
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.reset();
                mPlayer.release();
                shoutcast.stopStream();
                mPlayer = null;
                playState = false;
            }
            else {
                Log.d("Player", "Play Called");
                createMediaPlayer();
                getAudioFocus();

                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(shoutcast.startStream());
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidStreamURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }
        }
    };

    private void createMediaPlayer() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        // Make sure the media player will acquire a wake-lock while
        // playing. If we don't do
        // that, the CPU might go to sleep while the song is playing,
        // causing playback to stop.
        //
        // Remember that to use this, we have to declare the
        // android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
        // permission in AndroidManifest.xml.
        mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        // we want the media player to notify us when it's ready preparing,
        // and when it's done
        // playing:
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    private void startPlayer() {
        mPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Log.d("Player", "Starting Playback");
            mPlayer.start();
            playState = true;
            status.setText("Streaming");
        }               
    }

    private void getAudioFocus() {
        if (mAudioFocus != AudioFocus.Focused && mAudioFocusHelper != null
                && mAudioFocusHelper.requestFocus())
            mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.Focused;
    }

    private void giveUpAudioFocus() {
        if (mAudioFocus == AudioFocus.Focused && mAudioFocusHelper != null
                && mAudioFocusHelper.abandonFocus())
            mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.NoFocusNoDuck;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        playState = false;
        handler.post(handlePlayRequest);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        startPlayer();      
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onGainedAudioFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLostAudioFocus(boolean canDuck) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The Above Code is working Perfect when I played the Stream in ForeGround,

**But My Requirement is to Play the Stream in Background also(My Code Should play the Stream,If  the user is Interacting with the Other Applications Also)**

For that ,I have Created a Service Class to above Activity

Here is the Code:

**Activity:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Player extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Boolean playState = false;
    public static final float DUCK_VOLUME = 0.1f;
    private String artistName = null;
    private String trackName = null;

    private TextView artist;
    private TextView track;
    private TextView status;
    private Button play;

    Intent playbackServiceIntent;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        // create the Audio Focus Helper, if the Audio Focus feature is
        // available (SDK 8 or above)

        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist);
        artist.setSelected(true);

        track = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.track);
        track.setSelected(true);

        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

        play.setOnClickListener(this);

        playbackServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BackGroundService.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == play) {
            startService(playbackServiceIntent);
            Log.d("hi>>>>>", "gjgj");
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

**Service Class:**

```
import com.androidworkz.androidshoutcastlib.AndroidShoutcastLib;
import com.androidworkz.androidshoutcastlib.InvalidStreamURLException;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class BackGroundService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener,
        OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        MusicFocusable {
    private Boolean playState = false;
    private String station = "http://38.101.195.5:9156";
    public static final float DUCK_VOLUME = 0.1f;
    Runnable handlePlayRequest;

    enum AudioFocus {
        NoFocusNoDuck, // we don't have audio focus, and can't duck
        NoFocusCanDuck, // we don't have focus, but can play at a low volume
                        // ("ducking")
        Focused // we have full audio focus
    }

    private AudioFocus mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.NoFocusNoDuck;

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
    private AndroidShoutcastLib shoutcast;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    AudioFocusHelper mAudioFocusHelper = null;

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("onStartCommand>>>", "onStartCommand");

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // create the Audio Focus Helper, if the Audio Focus feature is
        // available (SDK 8 or above)
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            mAudioFocusHelper = new AudioFocusHelper(getApplicationContext(),
                    this);
        } else {
            mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.Focused; // no focus feature, so we always
                                                // "have" audio focus
        }
        shoutcast = new AndroidShoutcastLib();

        try {
            Log.d("Station>>>", station);

            shoutcast.setShoutcastUrl(station);

        } catch (InvalidStreamURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new BackgroundSound().execute();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("onDestroy>>>", "onDestroy");

        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
        mPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGainedAudioFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLostAudioFocus(boolean canDuck) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    private void giveUpAudioFocus() {
        if (mAudioFocus == AudioFocus.Focused && mAudioFocusHelper != null
                && mAudioFocusHelper.abandonFocus())
            mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.NoFocusNoDuck;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stopSelf();
    }

    private void getAudioFocus() {
        if (mAudioFocus != AudioFocus.Focused && mAudioFocusHelper != null
                && mAudioFocusHelper.requestFocus())
            mAudioFocus = AudioFocus.Focused;
    }

    private void createMediaPlayer() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        // Make sure the media player will acquire a wake-lock while
        // playing. If we don't do
        // that, the CPU might go to sleep while the song is playing,
        // causing playback to stop.
        //
        // Remember that to use this, we have to declare the
        // android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
        // permission in AndroidManifest.xml.
        mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        // we want the media player to notify us when it's ready preparing,
        // and when it's done
        // playing:
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    private class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.d("doInBackground>>>", "doInBackground");

            Log.d("run>>>", "run");

            if (playState) {
                Log.d("Player", "Stop Called");
                giveUpAudioFocus();
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.reset();
                mPlayer.release();
                shoutcast.stopStream();
                mPlayer = null;
                playState = false;
            } else {
                Log.d("Player", "Play Called");
                createMediaPlayer();
                getAudioFocus();

                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(shoutcast.startStream());
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidStreamURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

When I execute above Service Class,I'm able to play the Stream,but My Layout is disappering when control Comes to Service Class

One thing,I want to know that,My Conversion from Activity to Service is Correct or not?

Could any one Suggest me Correct Code?